# Read JESS Facts from Database

Tags: database, expert-system, jess

I am designing an Expert system in JESS and I would like to make it read facts from a Database instead of directly entering into Its interface.

Is there any predefined mechanism in JESS to do that? a sort of function maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no built in way, but it's easy to do directly in Jess, or in Java. A lot of what you'd need to do it from Java is [in the 'Library' chapter of the manual.](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/library.html#jess.Fact)

Comment: Dear Ernest, do you think it's possible to store the knowledge in a relational database instead of an ontology?  I want to create the rules in Jess and use a database to store recommendations, for matching rules and recommendation i use sql queries. Is it possible?

Comment: I mean is there any other way to create the knowledge base instead of using Ontology?  Can i store the knowledge in jess?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question; do you mean is it possible to use Jess without protégé? If so, the answer is yes, absolutely. If you read the Jess manual, you'll see that protégé isn't even mentioned once.

Comment: Ow, thanks God. Would u please mention its name to let me know what to search for.

Comment: Thank u by the way, you are great. nice job for Jess

Comment: Dear ernest, did u mean deftemplate to define entities?

Comment: I think you just need to sit down and read the manual; see link above, but start from the beginning. It's a good read, the author is brilliant :)

Comment: Dear ernest, i read it. It is absolutely brilliant. I have an off topic question. What kind of knowledge is created in jess? Is it a procedural code knowledge? Or it can define an ontology like protege?

Comment: The templates themselves together with some facts can be an ontology; the right-hand-sides of rules are procedural. Rules in general are *declarative knowledge.*

Comment: Dear Ernest, with your help i managed to write some rules and define some templates to inference. The system works perfectly. Now i want to create second level of rules to check first level rules' results and give them recommendations. first level rules tell if a patient is obese and have low exercise. second levels check different conditions and give medical guidelines. should i write the second level rules like first level or there is a more efficient way to implement this?